# This contract matches the deployed ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract on EtherScan

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin, etherscan

Using Openzeppelin CLI I created Upgradable Smart contract and Deployed it on my rinkeby Testnetwork thats all working fine.but after the deployment i check the source code of my contract on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/  it shows  my contract is verified and
Note:

> This contract matches the deployed ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract 0xEe03719900bcf6295871846DAe4711F7446b70C6.

And the source code which is on the etherscan is not my contract source code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your source code produces identical bytecode to an existing contract. I assume EtherScan only checks only for the first verified source code and byte code pair of a deployed contract.

This e.g. happens when you copy someone's else's code and only try to change some comments and naming.

Comment: Thanks  @Mikko Ohtamaa  i found solution for this issue and verified code successfully.

Comment: How did you go about solving it? You could just add the details for people facing smae issues

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes when you redeploy the same contract in remix. possible solution re verifies the contract again and go to https://etherscan.io/tokenapprovalchecker?
to delete the old one or the new contract address